# Normalizing Numbers to a 0-100% Range

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization, normalization

My end goal is to create a simple horizontal bar graph that colors a set of values from green down to red, depending on their relative differences.

It works fine when there is a large existing gap in values, for example it can look like this (the top value in this case is **37**, the bottom is **10**).

[image: Ranked with Variation]

However, if I attempt this with a set of numbers that are all in the same range, it no longer shows what I'm looking for, as they are all "green" because they are so relatively close to one another.

Here is what it looks like when the range is from **66** down to **62**:

[image: Ranked with almost no variation]

I have tried applying the 0-1 normalization function to this, such as:

```
x = a + (X - A) * (b - a) / (B - A)
```

In my C#, that looks like this:

```
    private static int Normalize(List<int> list, int currentValue) {

        int endOfScale = 1;
        int topOfScale = 100;
        int min = list.Min();
        int max = list.Max();

        var normalized = endOfScale + (currentValue - min) * (topOfScale - endOfScale) / (max - min);

        return normalized;

    }
```

[image: Normalization of Scale]

In the end, these values are being run through JavaScript on the client to produce the RGB color values via:

```
function getGreenToRed(percent){
    r = percent<50 ? 255 : Math.floor(255-(percent*2-100)*255/100);
    g = percent>50 ? 255 : Math.floor((percent*2)*255/100);
    return 'rgb('+r+','+g+',0)';
}
```

That could also be the problem, I'm trying to determine which side to attack here.

Comment: Why not '62 -> 1' is wrong? Clear your mind first. What is red, what is green and how fast is the transition?

Comment: So, if 66 is the max and therefore 100, what should be 61? Should the representative of 1 always be 1?

Comment: @Zohar I have edited the post to include the client-side JavaScript that does the val to rgb color conversion.  Perhaps that is the problem.  But if the set is [66, 65, 63, 63, 62, 61] it should come out as [green, rellow, mid-yellow, dark-yellow, red] ... something along those lines.   A relative chart showing all green is not very visually indicative of anything.

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. the question is what should 61 translate to? From my understanding, translating any range to 1-100 will surly take the lowest value as 1 and the highest as 100. Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled What I am looking for is a representative green to red color range regardless of the actual range of numbers. I'm not sure if I have to bring in a logarithmic aproach here.  For example, given the set [3,2,1] that would be 1=Green, 2=Yellow, 3=Red.  Given [90, 80, 70, 40, 5] that would be [Green, Light Green, Orange, Dark Orange, Red] or something along those lines.  Regardless of the size of the set or the actual range.  RGB or HSV, that is what I'm looking into now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You are correct, I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalizing 62 to 0 is exactly what you want. Just color the bar in accordance to the normalized value, but draw the length with the original value. Your normalized value indicates where your original value in the order of values is placed, but it is not the value it is to be drawn with.

```
public Color ColorFromNormalized(int normalized)
{
    if(normalized == 100)
        return Color.Green;
    if(normalized > 70)
        return Color.Yellow;
    if(normalized > 30)
        return Color.Orange;
    return Color.Red
}
```

Comment: That got me headed in the right direction, thanks.  I added my own answer with how I did it without the fixed colors, client-side with JavaScript in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here but accepting @Sebastian because that was what got me on the right path.

They key was this statement:

> Just color the bar in accordance to the normalized value, but draw the
>   length with the original value.

That was the trick.  I did not like the fixed-color approach, so I made it a little more advanced than that.  But it works.

Original range **62** to **66** without normalizing for color:

[image: Before Normalizing for Color]

After, same range:

[image: After normalizing for Color]

If it helps, the Normalize function is shown in the original question.

The client side JavaScript is the same, except I'm now passing in the *normalized* value into the JavaScript RGB function.

Here, the parameter *percent*, is the 0-100 *normalized percent*.

```
function getGreenToRed(percent){
    r = percent<50 ? 255 : Math.floor(255-(percent*2-100)*255/100);
    g = percent>50 ? 255 : Math.floor((percent*2)*255/100);
    return 'rgb('+r+','+g+',0)';
}
```